# Create SDE-file returns warning but creates the file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

When I create an SDE-file using arcpy I get the following warning:

> WARNING 000565: Could not connect to server.

This is the appropriate code

```
temp = r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp'
host = "myServer"
sdeFileName = "mySdeFile.sde"
service = "sde:oracle11g:myHost/myInstance:" + user
arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management(temp, sdeFileName, myHost, service, username = user, password = password, version = version)
```

However the file itself was created successfully and I can even put it into ArcCatalogs sde-connections-folder and open it in ArcCatalog. Thus I doubt the error occurs because of any missing privileges.

As this message is quite generic and can be caused by many different problems I don´t want to swallow it.

Has anyone a solution or at least an explanation for this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and Python 2.7 for 32bit.

EDIT: When I use

```
arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(temp, sdeFileName, "ORACLE", service, username = user, password = password, version = version)
```

instead it works without any problems.
However as I also have some customers that still use Application-Server-connections I cannot use this function as there´s no information on the actual host given within the `service`-paramater as opposed to the DirectConnect-syntax, where the paramater includes both the host and the database-instance.

So what I need is a function that works with all the following inputs:

1. Application-Server-connection (deprecated)

   `host = "myServer"`
   `service = "5151:mySdeInstance"`
2. Direct-Connect-connection

   `service = "sde:oracle11g:tnsName:user"`
   where `tnsName` corresponds the name for that connection within `tnsnames.ora`.
3. Easy-Connect-connection

   `service = "sde:oracle11g:myServer/user:user"`

Comment: You haven't provided enough information -- all the parameters are hidden in variables.

Comment: @Vince I´m not sure if the information I provided within the update will help any further, but here they are.

Comment: Are you really using a user-schema geodatabase? (This is not a recommended configuration).  Is the "user" variable anything other than "mySchema"? Still unclear: Is the arcpy command running in a 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: @Vince In our envireonemtn `mySchema` is identical to the user of the GDB, I´m not sure on the exact term however.

Comment: If you're not using 10.2.2 with the 23 patches applied, then that's your first task.  After that, I'm afraid you'll need to talk with Tech Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct connections and 3-tier connections with geoprocessing tools must be created with separate tools.  To supply a port or service name, try using the Create ArcSDE Connection File tool.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-arcsde-connection-file.htm

```
arcpy.CreateArcSDEConnectionFile_management(r'c:\connectionFiles',
                                        'gpserver',
                                        '5151',
                                        '',
                                        'toolbox',
                                        'toolbox',
                                        'SAVE_USERNAME',
                                        'SDE.DEFAULT',
                                        'SAVE_VERSION')
```

For a direct connection, use [CreateDatabaseConnection_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-connection.htm) as suggested above.

Comment: Have you even read my question? I need an appraoch that not only works for application-server-connections. Furtheremore you do not provide an Sde-filename but only a path-name and your parameters seems quite confusing to me. What is `toolbox`? If it is the username and password you´re also missing the `account_authentication`-param.

Comment: I realized that the method you mention may work for Direct/Eazy Connect also, but was actually designed for Application Server-connections only. Maybe you could add that for all other types we need `CreateDatabaseConnection` instead into your answer.

Comment: Gotcha.  I could have added this as a reply instead of an answer but I come across this question frequently. We're now 3 versions of ArcGIS since the ArcSDE component has been retired and documentation is getting harder and harder to find.